# Toggle Switch With HTML and PHP Form

Tags: php, html

I have switch in my HTML form like below

```
<div class="form-group">
             <span><b>GAME MODE?</b></span> &nbsp;<div class="btn-group" id="status" data-toggle="buttons">

              <label class="btn btn-default btn-on">
              <input type="radio" value="1" name="gamemode">ON</label>
              <label class="btn btn-default btn-off active">
              <input type="radio" value="0" name="gamemode" checked="checked">OFF</label>
            </div>
            </div>
```

On Submit form, I am getting all $_POST value but just not getting value of toggle switch. I think I am missing something in it. I am trying to get it like below in PHP

```
$gamemode=$_POST['gamemode'];
```

But its always empty. Can I know if anyone can help me for use properly toggle switch?

Thanks!

Comment: I see no form method here. Do you have a `<form method="post">` and a `submit` button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should have a form tag with method attribute set to post. Then once the submit button is pressed the form `$_POST` the data and you can retrieve that info using `$_POST['gamemode']`. I used the below code and tested and get a `1` when `ON` is submitted and a `0` when `OFF` is submitted.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span><b>GAME MODE?</b></span> &nbsp;<div class="btn-group" id="status" data-toggle="buttons">
    <form method="post">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-on">
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="gamemode">ON</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-off active">
        <input type="radio" value="0" name="gamemode" checked="checked">OFF</label>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>  
</div>
```